# Swift error: Couldn't lookup symbols with @State variable

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, debugging, lldb

I am currently using Xcode version 15.0 and would like to implement an arrow in the porter. When using a stand variable, as it is on the Internet on various sites, has recently arisen a previously unknown problem and namely since Xcode version 15.0 the following variable can no longer be read:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct commands: Commands{
    
    @ObservedResults(Book.self) var allBooks
    
    @State private var isShowing = false
    @State private var test = "test"
    private var test2 = "tessssst"
    var fileManager = FileManagerSingelton.shared
    
    var body: some Commands {
        CommandMenu("import"){
            Button("Import File"){
                isShowing.toggle()
            }                        //$isShowing is probably the error and becomes nil  
            .fileImporter(isPresented: $isShowing, allowedContentTypes: [.item]) {result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let url):
                    pass
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                    return
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For debugging I have added the two variables Test and Test2

```
(lldb) po test
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  SpeedReader.commands.test.getter : Swift.String
(lldb) p test
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  SpeedReader.commands.test.getter : Swift.String
(lldb) po test2
"tessssst"
(lldb) p test2
(String) "tessssst"
```

I haven't really found comparable problems on Steckoverflow, unfortunately.

Comment: You can use underscore before the property name, `po _test` or `p _test`

Comment: sometimes the error can come from somewhere else, what is `pass`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `po _test.wrappedValue` returns the desired value. But when I use `_isShowing.projectedValue` in the code, the program crashes again with the same error message.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine `pass` is only there for a code part, which is not so important. I have taken it out here to make it easier to read.

Comment: I didn't tell you to use it in the code, my comment was only for the debugger. And I have no idea what crash or error you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The specific error is that lldb can't find the getter for your `@State` variable.  Presumably the `@State` macro is causing swift to generate getters & setters around your variable to do its job, but the compiler is choosing to "in-line" uses of the getter, rather than emitting a regular method that can be called in the debugger.

You might be able to use `v` to examine the variable.  `v` does static inspection of values, rather than calling code in the debugee as `p` does, and so can sometimes see past this sort of problem.

But if you have the time, it's also worth filing a bug with the swift bug reporter:

https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/

At `-ONone` swift ought to make getters callable in the debugger.